# css circle rotation with text inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you guys tell me how to make the hallo text to centre inside the circle?
The circle is not currently working the way it should in IE8 and Firefox.
Does anyone have any ideas / suggestions that could fix this?
I have provided a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9r4Y/)

Here is my code below (It is all in my Fiddle above)

**CSS**

```
 .spinner span em {
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.spinner span:first-child em {
  left: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate-lt; 
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.spinner span:last-child em {
  left: -100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate-rt; 
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="spinner">
<span><em></em></span>
<span><em></em></span>

hallo
</div>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You're using `-webkit-` prefixes and wondering why it doesn't work in IE and Firefox...?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: can you tell me how to fix it in firefox and ie

Answer (score 1):

To centre your text, use `text-align:center` for horizontal alignment, and set `line-height:300px` (with `300px` being equal to the element's height) for vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtYJ4/), I've placed a wrapper div

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="spinner">
      <span><em></em></span>
      <span><em></em></span>  
    </div>
    <div class="text">hallo<div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index:10;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:300px;    
}

.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #aaa;
}
.spinner:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}

.spinner span em {
  background: #0e728e;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; 
}

/* No need to edit below this line */

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-rt {
  0% {    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  25% {   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  50% {   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  75% {   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
  100% {  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate-lt {
  0% {    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  25% {   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  50% {   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  75% {   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
  100% {  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.spinner {
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.spinner span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.spinner span:first-child {
  left: 0;
}

.spinner span:last-child {
  left: 50%;
}

.spinner span em {
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.spinner span:first-child em {
  left: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate-lt; 
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.spinner span:last-child em {
  left: -100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate-rt; 
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
 }
```

Comment: @Woolnut: can you tell me how to fix it in firefox or ie